# Should I free a loaded module when disposing the object?

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop, dispose

I'm loading a COM dll using this method:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
private extern static IntPtr LoadLibrary(string librayName);
```

Should I release the dll using:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

or just let the application termination handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `FreeLibrary` when you're done using a DLL that you loaded using `LoadLibrary`. This will not be an issue unless your application is long-running and you load many of these DLLs, or unless you would want to update the DLL on disk (it would be locked as long as it's loaded).

By the way, why are you using `LoadLibrary` to load a COM DLL and not using TLBIMP to create a .NET-accessible wrapper?

Comment: +1 And to clarify a little further, *only* free those DLLs that you loaded using `LoadLibrary`. You should not free any of the system DLLs like "system32", "kernel32", etc., *or* any DLLs whose handle you obtain with `GetModuleHandle`. Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683152.aspx) for details.

Comment: I am using TLBIMP, but I don't like to handle un\registration of my COM objects every version deployment.

Comment: @HuBeZa: You *should* be using an installer that takes care of that for you. Doing it manually is a giant pain in the rear. But a setup program will actually make versioning easier, rather than more difficult.